# resize superview with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, subview

I'm asking a question about resizing the superview with autolayout!

Firstly, I create a custom cell in interface builder. There is only a custom view with height of ***0*** in the cell. The top,bottom,left and right directions of the view all have constraints to the cell.contentView(view.superview).

And then, I initiate two labels in the view and set texts for labels like this:

```
- (void)customView
{   _title = [UILabel newAutoLayoutView];
    _text = [UILabel newAutoLayoutView];
    _title.numberOfLines = 0;
    _text.numberOfLines = 0;
    _title.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _text.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _title.text = @"this is the title";
    _text.text = @"this is the text";
    [_view addSubview:_title];
    [_view addSubview:_text];

    [_title autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop withInset:5.0f];
    [_title autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft withInset:5.0f];
    [_title autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight withInset:5.0f];
    [_title autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:_text withOffset:-10.0f];

    [_text autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft withInset:5.0f];
    [_text autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight withInset:5.0f];
    [_text autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:5.0f];
}
```

But at runtime, the result turns out to be crashed with layout error.While I think the superview will resize when the labels texts are set.I'm so sure the layout is correct.I think it may be something wrong about the priority of constraints set.

Does anyone encounter the same question?I'm appreciating any help.

NOTE:the mattered point is that the height of the view is ***0***!!!